# How to rotate home screen

Tags: android, screen-rotation

I used:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

But only current screen is changed.
I want to change orientation of all screens on device.
How to rotate the home screen?

Comment: I think you need to install another launcher. Most stock launchers won't rotate unfortunately. I know Go Launcher does. Maybe there are some more.

Answer (score 1):

Setting -> and select Screen rotation

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file of your project just add this way with activity tag

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

and if you want your screen in particular orientation then add above properties in all activity tag..

Comment: Thks for your answer, but i want my app can rotate home screen.
Example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dp.applockorientation

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your qus is, you want to change orientation for all apps, If Am I correct, then you can't change rotation all the apps orientation in android, but you can change orientation in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your every activity in the manifest declaration

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"/>
```

This will rotate your screen if the device is rotated and the device orientation is set to auto